# Mongoose query works perfect on Windows 10, but hangs on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

**Context**

I've developed a React system and the login is handled by an API that hands out JWT tokens. I've developed everything on Windows 10 and I will deploy it on a EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS unit.

**The problem**

The API runs on Express. The app is able to make a DB connection (which is hosted on MongoDB Atlas) on both Windows and Linux (even though it takes much longer on Linux). However, the app is not able to make a query. The find or findOne functions both don't give any feedback, while they work perfectly fine on my Windows machine.

**The relevant code**

The code is as follows:

*App.js*

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

//Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, () => {
    console.log("Connected to DB!");
});

//Import routes
...
const authentication = require('./routes/Auth');
...

//Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Route middleware
...
app.use('/auth', authentication);
...

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

app.listen(3003, () => {
    console.log("server is up and running");
});
module.exports = app;
```

*Auth.js*

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../model/user');

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const {registerValidation, loginValidation} = require('../model/Validation');

...

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    //Validate the data
    const {error} = loginValidation(req.body);
    if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    //Check if exists
    //Application fails here
    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function (err) {console.log(err)});
    if(!user) return res.status(400).send('Email or password is wrong');

    //Check if password is correct
    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if(!validPass) return res.status(400).send('Email or password is wrong');

    //Create and assign a token
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: 60 * 240});
    res.header('auth-token', token).send(token);
})

...

module.exports = router;
```

*user.js (the model)*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 255
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 255
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 1024,
        min: 6
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**What I've done**

- I've checked for errors, but can't seem to find any.
- I've checked the connection, and it is able to connect to the server.
- I've changed the connection parameters, which did not change any behaviour.

**My goal**

I want to be able to run the API on my Linux Ubuntu VPS so I can deploy the actual React application. Right now the login obviously doesn't work. All the other endpoints in the API (has a lot of functions / endpoints, but these not related to either the login endpoint or MongoDB) are working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was super simple actually... I noticed my readystate was on 0, so I added the following lines to my App.js file to see what went wrong exactly:

```
//Connect to DB
mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref) {
    console.log('Connected to mongo server.');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Could not connect to mongo server!');
    console.log(err);
});
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, () => {
    console.log("Connected to DB!");
}).then(r => console.log(r.connections));
```

After that, I noticed that my connection was closed and I was having a TransientTransactionError.

**The solution**

Well I just forgot to add the IP adress on the new server to my IP whitelist.